# String array how to overcome the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, arraylist

In situation where you are not sure about the length of an array attempting to read a value position from a non existing value lead to

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=x; index=x
```

For example in an excel importing function you expect 10 columns but the file has 9 columns then reading the 10th column result to this exception.

what is the best way of dealing with this kind of exception?

Comment: checking the length of the array before trying to access the index ?

Comment: Each array hast it's length.

Comment: array's index starts from 0.

Comment: Please Show your code.

Comment: length = arrayname.length
if(index>=lenght)
{
//do stuff
}

Comment: Blackbelt just won the internet.

Comment: Check the lenght of the string and according to that read the value...

Comment: ok guys thanks for your reaction. i really do this every day on arrays but could not think to do it for string array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - the indexes of the arrays are starting from 0, not from 1 and if you get 10 columns, the last one will be with index 9. If you use a simple array, you could check the size of it like this:

```
String[] members = ["He", "She", "It", "The dog"];
int arraySize = members.length;
```

If you use ArrayList, you could check the size of the array like this:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
int arraySize = myList.size();
```

And then you could make a for loop through the values like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< arraySize; i++){ ... }
```

or check if your current index is in the array like this:

```
//index is a variable with the current index of the element you want
if(index < arraySize){ ... } //do something
else ...
```

I hope this will help you to avoid the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :)